# PHP and Ajax not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer

So, I have developed a live search function on my site but, no big surprise, it doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer. I have tested and it won't work in IE9 and IE8 and I know it works as I want in Chrome and Fire Fox. The Ajax I used I took from the W3Schools website and it seems to be working there. It might even be the PHP I used, but I'm not really sure what the problem is. I'm just guessing that it's either the Ajax or PHP. Anyone know what's wrong? It is located at -RETRACTED URL- if it helps. Thanks!

Ajax in my HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var keyword = ''; // add this!
var city = ''; // add this!
var state = ''; // add this!
var country = ''; // add this!

function showHint(keyword, city, state, country) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(keyword.length == 0 && city.length == 0 && state.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?keyword=" + keyword + "&city=" + city + "&state=" + state + "&country=" + country, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

PHP for the live search:

```
<?php
//get the parameters from URL
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$city = $_GET['city'];
$state = $_GET['state'];
$country = $_GET['country'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ClinicName LIKE '%$keyword%' AND LocationCity LIKE '%$city%' AND LocationRegion LIKE '%$state%' AND LocationCountry LIKE '%$country%' ORDER BY ClinicName ASC") or die(mysql_error());

if($query){//If query successfull
    if(mysql_affected_rows()!=0){//and if atleast one record is found
        echo '
        <tr>
            <th>Clinic Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>';
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ //Display the record
            $replace = str_replace(" ", "-", $rows['ClinicName']);
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td><a href="clinic.php?userid='.$rows['UserID'] .'">'.$rows['ClinicName'].'</a></td>
                <td>'.$rows['Phone1'].'-'.$rows['Phone2'].'-'.$rows['Phone3'].'</td>
                <td>'.$rows['LocationCity'].', '.$rows['LocationRegion'].' '.$rows['LocationZip'].', '.$rows['LocationCountry'].'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'No Results for:<br />Clinic Name: '.$keyword.'<br />City: '.$city.'<br />State: '.$state.'<br />Country: '.$country.'';//No Match found in the Database
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Parameter Missing in the URL';//If URL is invalid
}
?>
```

Comment: Check if it works in chrome or firefox first please

Comment: Yeah, it does. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: Did you personally test it in Chrome?

Comment: Yeah, I did. And it's all working as I want it.

Comment: why take all the pain, switch to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE won't let you innerHTML a table. You can find this information here: [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239832)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*define variable d as date:* `var d = new Date();`

*then add to GET*

```
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?keyword=" + keyword + "&city=" + city + "&state=" + state + "&country=" + country + "&q=" + d, true);     
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```